# How to have multiple devices within an ecosystem call Azure IoT field gateway through an API?

Tags: azure, iot, gateway

I've multiple devices in an ecosystem that needs to send messages to Azure IoT Hub. If I create a field gateway in the device, how to call the field gateway endpoint (API) from multiple modules to send messages?

Comment: What's the interface(communication protocol) between your devices and the field gateway?

Comment: The devices intercommunicate through Ethernet/IP. I'm yet to decide on the protocol to be used between devices and field gateway...it could be HTTP or MQTT

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a single device with multiple sensors, then you don't need to use a Field Gateway. Your device could be connected to send messages directly to Azure IoT Hub.

A Field Gateway is for connecting 1 or more devices behind the Gateway to Azure IoT Hub, specifically devices that can't connect to Azure IoT Hub themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I might have miscommunicated with the term module. It's actually multiple devices within a ecosystem which tries to connect through field gateway.